# Reject and Edit hijacks proposed example

Tags: discussion, bug, documentation

I rejected a [proposed example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/13928?draftId=13556) for a documentation topic because it had some issues. Then I decided to improve it by clicking that "Improve draft" button that appears after the rejection.

My improvements have been approved, but now it looks like I was the one who created [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/108/resources/4763/string-formatting-in-strings-xml#t=201607212146548821726), which is not true.

Is this intended or a bug?